# my mesh instance seems black in godot engine always

Tags: textures, mesh, godot

When I create a new mesh instance in spatial, mesh always seems black in the editor and debug and I didn't use any gdscript

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In the panel in which you change color, in the same pannel you can see a option named flag, click on it and the unshaded option then you can see the colours.

Answer (score 0):

add a world environment node then create a new environment there is a setting called ambient light click on it then set the sky contribution to 0 then you can set the color of the light! add a directional light for shadows and shading

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).